# Area of region using formulas from geometry

Tags: calculus

The task is to find the area of the region between the curves using formulas from geometry. I can't figure it out which formula should i use it. Can somebody please help me? :)

[image: GRAPH of the functions]

Answer (score 1):

There are many formulas that are applicable, as can be seen from the other answers, but to use any of them you have to start by finding the three intersection points. From there, you can find the three side lengths and use Heron’s formula ([Yulmart’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2301631/265466)), compute one of the altitudes and the use the formula for the area of a triangle, take half of the area of a paralellogram (the same as the previous one, really), &c.

Answer (score 0):

Find the intersection points between the 3 lines and then the vectors that connect the points. You can then find the magnitude of the vectors which will give you the length of each side of the triangle. You can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, draw horizontal and vertical lines passing through each vertices of the triangle, and write the searched area as a difference between the area of a rectangle and of three right-angled triangles.

Or you can go aster using integrals, but I suppose that's not the point of this exercise...

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the intersections first $A=(-2,-3)$, $B=(4,-6)$, and $C=(0,1)$. Now draw a vertical line at $x=4$. It intersects blue line at $y=9$, call this $D=(4,9)$. The area of $ABC$ is equal to area of $ABD$ minus area of $CBD$